# What are all of OperaGX's supported file types for creating add-ons?

Tags: opera-extension

I am trying to create an animated wall paper for OperaGX in the add-ons section, and I've uploaded an .mp4 twice and it's telling me that .mp4 is not supported. I would like to know all of the supported file types that could be accepted, I am currently converting the .mp4 to a .gif .

Comment: .mp4 seems to not be supported either.

Answer (score 0):

OperaGX only supports the following file types for creating add-ons: .gif, .jpg, and .png.

Comment: I've tried .gif, but it seems as it did not work. It continues to tell me that the file type is not supported.